# Multiple actions within a NGRX effect

Tags: redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

While learning Angular and NGRX, ran into what I thought would be simple example of common problem but having trouble understanding best way to accomplish the control logic with in the Redux store\effects patterns.

General Process:

User types in credit card info, hit pay button > Dispatch a "GetTokenAction" from component > Make an Http request to external 3rd party API to tokenize > Submit that information if successful to Payment API

Here is my latest attempt:

```
    @Effect() getToken$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(TokenizerActions.GET_TOKEN)
    .pipe(switchMap((action: TokenizerActions.GetTokenAction) => {
        return this.TokenizerApiService.getToken(action.payload)
            .pipe(
                map(tokenResponse => {
                        console.log(tokenResponse);
                        // service will return 200 with "declined" status. In this case I want to treat it like an Error.
                        if (tokenResponse.results.Error != null) {
                            return new TokenizerActions.GetTokenFailedAction(tokenResponse.results.Error.messages);
                        }
                        // What is best practice here?  Call Payment Service? Dispatch Actions? Where should this mapping logic live?
                        const paymentRequest: PaymentRequest = new PaymentRequest();
                        paymentRequest.token = tokenResponse.results.token;
                        paymentRequest.amount = action.payload.amount;
                        paymentRequest.customerNumber = action.payload.customerNumber;
                        paymentRequest.correlationId = tokenResponse.results.correlation_id;
                        // this does not work, "dispatched an invalid action: undefined" error.
                        mergeMap((payReq: PaymentRequest) => [new paymentActions.MakePaymentAction(paymentRequest),
                        new TokenizerActions.GetTokenSuccessAction(tokenResponse.results.token)]);
                    }),
                catchError(error => of(new TokenizerActions.GetTokenFailedAction(error)))
            );
    }));

constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private TokenizerApiService: TokenizerApiService,
    private paymentApiService: PaymentApiService
) { }
```

Question/Considerations:

Is the effect the appropriate place to handle this? The first working version had the component controlling the flow and dispatching multiple actions, could also be handled within the services, not sure which is best practice.

What is the preferred method for error notification within the Effects pattern? Online and in sample application there are a lot of simple examples, but I am having trouble translating that to a slightly more complex example (inspect response and then throw errors and stop processing as needed).  Currently the application is doing something like this:

```
    <span class="error" *ngFor="let error of tokenErrors$ | async">{{error.description}}</span>
    <span class="error" *ngFor="let error of paymentErrors$ | async">{{error.description}}</span>
    <div class="success" *ngIf="(payment$ | async)?.transactionStatus === 'approved'">Success</div>

this.paymentErrors$ = this.store.select(state => state.payment.paymentErrorMessages);
this.tokenErrors$ = this.store.select(state => state.token.tokenErrorMessages);
this.payment$ = this.store.select(state => state.payment.paymentStatus);
```

Can it be simpler? Should errors be combined into one PayError array? Is there a catch in the component level if subscribed or is it all to be handled in the effects level?

Answer (score 2):

First, don't do the arrow function directly and create selectors instead.

Secondly, select a ViewModel (`transactionInfo`) that's needed for this component with one selector instead of having 3 different ones. You can combine multiple selectors to achieve that.
The result could be pushed higher in the template with `*ngIf`, for example

```
<ng-container *ngIf="transactionInfo$ | async as transactionInfo">
  <span class="error" *ngFor="let error of tokenErrors">{{error.description}}</span>
    <span class="error" *ngFor="let error of transactionInfo.paymentErrors">{{error.description}}</span>
    <div class="success" *ngIf="transactionInfo.transactionStatus === 'approved'">Success</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you for this response, it helped clarify displaying and combining errors when the error lists are created in multiple reducers. Can you add insight into the root of the question, How to properly chain dependent http calls and what the flow of successes/errors actions from the effect should be within the ngrx/redux pattern?

Comment: The answer would be 'it depends' - sometimes it's best to put that logic into one Effect, sometimes you can split across multiple Effects.
In this particular case I'd probably have everything in one Effect.